# How do you create a checkbox that retains its value on a form render for a Ruby on Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I am doing is pretty simple but the value is never retained on form being rendered because of failing validation.  I basically have a `Article` model that has a `published` boolean field that can either be `true` or `false`.

If I change the value from say its initial render value of `true` by unchecking the checkbox, and then I fail validations and the form gets re-rendered, then it shows the original value of `true` in the database.  How do I retain the recent change even on a validation issue and the form gets re-rendered like this?  Thanks

form code:

```
= form_for @article, :url => article_path do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :description
  = f.check_box :published
  = f.submit "Update"
```

html code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="article[published]">
<input id="article_published" class="pull-left" type="checkbox" value="1" name="article[published]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding published to attr_accessible fixed the issue.